# pass variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce

I want to pass a calculator result to a php file and the result will change the product quantity.

I want to set the starting value to be the result from the calculator page.
I have a button on calculator page and after clicking the button the page will go the product page and pass the calculated result to product quantity.

I don't know how to pass it to this php file.

This is my html

```
     <div>Total: <span id="finaltotalresult">6.864</span>metric tons</div>

    <form method="post"  action="http://carboncreditcapital.com/offset">
    <input type="hidden" name="finalresult">
    <input type="submit" value="Offset Now" id="offset" >
    </form>
```

javascript:

```
        $("#offset").on('click',function(){
            var text =$("#finaltotalresult").text();
            var val = Math.round(parseFloat(text));
            $.post('/dev/wp-content/themes/responsive-child/functions.php',{val: val}, function(){

                });
        });
```

This is the php:

```
   $val= $_POST['val'];

     add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
      function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {

         $args['input_value']   = $val; // Starting value
         $args['max_value']     = 80;   // Maximum value
          $args['min_value']    = 1;    // Minimum value
          $args['step']         = 1;    // Quantity steps
          return $args;
    }
```

Comment: Please restrain from posting debugging requests on stackoverflow. Instead, ask a concrete programming question. *"Something not successfully"* does not qualify as such. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: The form will get submitted unless you stop the default action; i.e. use `return false;` in your click handler.

Comment: I am quite confused now. I want the button link to the product page and i want submit the value to a different php file. How should i do this? Thanks.

Comment: @user3371790: Maybe start with some tutorial that explains it to you? I don't wanna sound rude but what you ask for is quite a lot (in the sense of which things work for that and how they work together).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've most likely a scope problem here with the `$val` variable. As you read it outside of the function

```
$val = $_POST[ 'val' ];
```

but you use it inside the function *withouth* importing it, it's not available there in.

So all you might need to do (the rest of the code doesn't look too wrong but it's hard to tell as I can not reproduce with your example code) is to import that variable there in. An easy way with your code is to use a closure:

```
$val = $_POST[ 'val' ];

add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 
    function ( $args, $product ) use ( $val ) 
    {
         $args[ 'input_value' ] = $val; // Starting value
         $args[ 'max_value'   ] = 80;   // Maximum value
         $args[ 'min_value'   ] = 1;    // Minimum value
         $args[ 'step'        ] = 1;    // Quantity steps

         return $args;
    }, 10, 2 );
```

The other alternative is to make use of the super-global inside your filter function.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the value of the hidden field same as what's in

```
<input type="hidden" name="finalresult" value="setValueHereUsingBelowJS">

<script>
$('input[name=finalresult]').val(
$('#finaltotalresult').html()
);
</script>
```

And to access on the server, use `$_POST['finalresult'];`

Comment: For the form action which address should i use? i have one url is for the php file and the other url is for the page that i want the button leads to.

Comment: @user3371790 If you want button to lead to a specific page, then your PHP code should be placed on that page. Basically, you can only go to one url on button click. So, all the code that you want to have should be on that url, whether its php or html.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="result" value="123">
```

to read it on the receiving php:

```
$result = $_POST['result'];
```

Comment: There ain't no input fields with an ajax request. So you could also suggest to drive with a buggy on the moon if you allow me to exaggerate a little. (it's most likely not your fault as the question is actually pretty baldy worded for a Q&A site like stackoverflow)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_serializearray

Comment: I assume you posted that link because you think it tells the opposite to what I've just commented. But rest assured it doesn't. Serialize is not in use here. Read the code before posting, it's not all the same only it has the jquery tag.

Comment: i'm only posting alternatives to the person who asked, since the qn was quite open.

Comment: if the question is "quite open", don't answer it. Ask the OP to make it more clear (and if you can't comment yet better get some rep with better questions as these open questions are not bringing you forward)